# How to close NavigationWindow by a button of its page (VB WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, navigationwindow

I am a new of VB WPF

Now I have a NavigetionWindow and set a page to be source,

in the page I place a button and I would like to close the whole application by pressing it,

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call Application.Shutdown() (this is C#), there are restrictions to this call so look at the MSDN link below for  those restrictions.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx

Comment: I can't use this. Some partial codes here


Class MainWindow
    Private Sub btExit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btExit.Click


        Application.ShutDown()


    End Sub


End Class

VS say: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

what should the object be referenced?